# How to remove rows in a dataframe considering there are duplicates in one column of dataframe

Tags: r

Hi dear I have a little problem with a dataframe that has duplicates in a column. I would like to remove the rows where a column presents duplicates. For example my dataframe is like this:

```
Value   City    Card.Type   ID
100   Michigan    Silver    001
120   Angeles     Gold      002
NA    Kansas      Gold      002
500   Michigan    Silver    001
800   Texas       Basic     005
```

You can see that in `ID` column there are two duplicates one for `001` and one for `002`. I was using `unique` function but I don't get to erase that duplicates. I would like to get someone like this:

```
 Value   City    Card.Type   ID
 100   Michigan    Silver    001
 120   Angeles     Gold      002
 800   Texas       Basic     005
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of which should only be done with its "positive" version. The danger in using the construction -which() is that when none of the rows or items match the test, the result of the `which()` is `numeric(0)` and `-numeric(0)` will return 'nothing', when the correct result is 'everything'. Use use:

```
 dat[!duplicated(dat), ]
```

In this case there were no duplicated rows, but the OP thought that some should be removed so obviously it was only two or three columns were under consideration. This is easy to accommodate. Just do the duplication test on 2 or three columns:

```
 dat[ !duplicated(dat[ , 2:3] ) , ]
```

Comment: I didn't know duplicated would combine columns in a data frame like that. Nice.

Comment: `duplicated` is generic and there is a data.frame method

Comment: @dayne, type `methods(duplicated)` to see the methods available.

Answer (score 3):

Use the function `duplicated`.

Something like:

```
data.subset <- data[!duplicated(data$ID),]
```

Duplicated returns a true/false vector. The second duplicated entry in the vector will always return `TRUE`.